# Is it possible to use a control's property value in visual state definitions of its template?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I wrote a custom control in WPF, I defined some visual states in the template, and I wanted to use some of the control's property value in the animation declararion. I tried binding and template binding, but it didn't work.
I googled some articles, because visual state manager has it's own logical tree, the binding to template parent won't work.
I wonder is there any way to archive my goal. If it is not, the visual state would be much less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot use `Binding` because of `Freezable` issues.
2. So, define a `StaticResource` and change its value in `PropertyChangedCallback` of your `DependencyProperty`.
3. Define a do-nothing `VisualState` without any `Storyboard`.
4. Now, in `PropertyChangedCallback` in step 2, refresh `VisualState` by first going to (3.), and then to needed one. This will refresh immediately.